# Vim: access to system clipboard via ssh - Linux to OS X

Tags: linux, macos, vim, ssh

I'm Linux user who often needs to work on remote OS X server via SSH. I prefer vim (neovim) editor but I have problem with copy/paste to/from system clipboard via SSH. When I try to copy line `"*yy` it saves on remote OS X clipboard. Is there a way to save it to my Linux clipboard instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you can just open remote file on your linux machine like:

```
:e scp://user@host/relative/path/from/home.txt
```

Another solution to copy directly from ssh session would be X11 forwarding in ssh which connects system clipboard between remote and local machine.

1. Enable X11Forwarding on the SSH server side in `/etc/ssh/sshd.conf`
2. Use the -Y option for ssh client to enable it when connecting:
   `ssh -Y your_server`

Now you can copy in the remote Vim using `"*yy` and paste it locally in Vim using `"*p` or paste it in any GUI app using <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer! I open vim on remote OS X system and it's a little bit inconvenient to open vim on local machine and connect to file every time when I need to copy some text. But if there is no way I will do it :-)

Comment: @Artkik posted another solution to suit your needs.