# Not able to paste yanked file of a remote vim file on a local vim file

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I followed some of the solutions here on stackoverflow, and almost each one of them has different solution from the other. 
I am trying to copy the entire content of a file on remote sever by doing:

```
vi file1
```

once inside the file I am doing:

```
:%y
```

That returns "1200 lines yanked "

Then I go to my another vi file on my local machine. I do:

```
vi file2
```

Then I tried pasting using `ctrl p`, `ctrl R` inside the empty vi file and many other commands it didn't work.
I even tried `cat dump.sql | xclip`. That didn't either. I am running ubuntu 14.04. can somebody please tell me how to achieve this Copy all and paste thing??

Comment: Use secure copy `scp` or enable **X11 forwarding** on that machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vim: access to system clipboard via ssh - Linux to OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107927/vim-access-to-system-clipboard-via-ssh-linux-to-os-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of these answers didn't work for me. I don't know if I got the syntax wrong or something. It was confusing for me. Here is what I did. I will put it in a very clear way.

First make sure you can ssh into your server. For that copy your local **/.ssh/id_rsa.pub** and paste it on your ec2 instance **/.ssh/authorized_keys**. So now try ssh into your server like `ssh <your ubuntu user>@<ec2_public_ip>`. If you were able to login to your server you are good for next step.

Find the path of the filename you want to download by doing this:

```
find "$(cd ..; pwd)" -name "filename"
```

You'll get the path. Copy that path. Next

Type this: On your local system

```
-$ scp ssh <your ubuntu user>@<your ec2 ip>:<the path you copied> <and the path on your local to download>
```

This will do it for you. I hope this is clear for if any rookie like myself gets stuck next time.

Answer (score 1):

When you ssh into a server and use vim you are using the server's vim not your vim.

There isn't anything wrong with your vim or the server's vim.

if you are looking to copy an entire file I would just use scp to pull the file down to your computer.

as @ Meninx - メネンックス said you could try something like this `:e scp://user@host/relative/path/from/home.txt`
if you wanted to do the entire operation in your vim.

The above code is from [Vim: access to system clipboard via ssh - Linux to OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107927/vim-access-to-system-clipboard-via-ssh-linux-to-os-x)

Comment: So once I open my file using `vi filename` on ec2 ubuntu I should do `:e scp://user@host/relative/path/from/filename `  ? This would work?

Comment: no open vim on your computer and run that command, of course `user@host/relative/path/from/filename` would have to be the correct host user and path.

Comment: So I did this ` scp -i ~/Desktop/file.pem deploy@ip_number:/home/deploy/apps/myapp/shared/config/database.yml /home/mypc/Desktop` And it says **Permission denied (public key)**. Even when I have set my local id_rsa.pub on server's authorized_keys.

Answer (score 0):

The way -I do this- (open to improvements!), is by scp-ing the file from within vim.

From shell:

- vi file2

Then within vim:

- :scp user@host:/file/path/file1 .

  - (prompted for password if not using pubkey)
  - (assuming the cwd is okay to store the file in)
- :r file1

For the scp:// solution recommended by nzajt, it seems one has to enable these ([based on the link he provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107927/vim-access-to-system-clipboard-via-ssh-linux-to-os-x)):

> - Enable X11Forwarding on the SSH server side in /etc/ssh/sshd.conf
> - Use the -Y option for ssh client to enable it when connecting: ssh -Y your_server

I was unable to get the scp:// solution to work.

Comment: I did as you mentioned. But first I confirmed if I can ssh into my server, so I could. Next I opened a empty vi file on local and entered `:scp   deploy@ec2ip:/home/deploy/apps/myapp/shared/config/database.yml` then I got this **e33 No previous substitute regular expression**

Comment: Hey mate you may be missing the second argument to scp to specify the destination for the source file? Let me know how you go.

Comment: Something like this? `scp -i ~/Desktop/file.pem deploy@ip_number:/home/deploy/apps/myapp/shared/config/datab‌​ase.yml /home/mypc/Desktop`