# Vim copy and paste between remote vim instances using tmux

Tags: vim, remote-server, tmux

Working on a remote server I cannot copy and paste between one vim instance and another. I have installed gVim with +clipboard, along with xclip. I use tmux to split panes, and work concurrently.

In my vimrc
`set clipboard+=unnamedplus`

I tried copying with y and "+y and "*y, and paste with p, "*p, "+p, and ctrl+shift+v.

I'm so confused why this is not working now, maybe an x11 problem. What is a robust way I can set this up to copy and paste between two panes on a remote tmux?

Comment: [Everything you need to know about Tmux copy paste - Ubuntu](http://www.rushiagr.com/blog/2016/06/16/everything-you-need-to-know-about-tmux-copy-pasting-ubuntu/).

Comment: And it keeps going on and on.

Comment: @phd that link was helpful and does indeed give a way to copy and paste between tmux windows, though it is not very satisfying. Since it uses tmux rather than vim. I want to copy to register and paste from there. Copy and paste in tmux, copies line numbers and I can't go further through a file. It seems like it should not be this hard. I'm wondering if I should ssh with -x or -X?

Comment: [-Y](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36108028/7976758)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using

```
" Copy Paste on System Clipboard
function Func2X11()
:call system('xclip -selection c', @r)
endfunction

vnoremap <F9> "ry:call Func2X11()<cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Press `control+insert` = **copy**

Press `shift+insert` = **paste**